# remove fragments in a sentence [puzzle]

Tags: string, algorithm, hash

### **Question:**

Write a program to remove fragment that occur in "all" strings,where a fragment 
is 3 or more consecutive word.

**Example:**

**Input::**

s1 = "It is raining and I want to drive home.";

s2 = "It is raining and I want to go skiing.";

s3 = "It is hot and I want to go swimming.";

**Output::**

s1 = "It is raining drive home.";

s2 = "It is raining go skiing.";

s3 = "It is hot go swimming.";

**Removed fragment** = "and i want to"

The program will be tested again large files.
Efficiency will be taken into consideration.

**Assumptions:** Ignore capitalization ,punctuation. but preserve in output.

**Note:** Take care of cases like

a a a a a b c b c b c b c where removing would create more fragments.

### My Solution: *(which i think is not the most efficient)*

1. Hash three word phrases into an int and store them in an array, for all strings.
   reduces to array of numbers like

   1 2 **3** 4 5 
   **3** 5 7 9 8
   9 **3** 1 7 9

*Problem reduces to intersection of arrays.*

sort the arrays. (k * nlogn)

keep k pointers. if all equal match found. else increment the pointer pointing to least value.
To solve for the Note above. I was thinking of doing a lazy delete, i.e mark phrases for deletion and delete at the end.

Are there cases where my solution might not work?  Can we optimize my solution/ find the best solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is as already suggested by izomorphius:

Replace each word with a single "letter" in a big alphabet(i.e. hash the worlds in some way), remove whitespaces and punctuation.

For the second you don't need to know the longest common substring - you just want to erase it from all the strings.
Note that this is equivalent to erasing all common substrings of length exactly 3, because if you have a longer commmon substring, then its substrings with length 3 are also common.
To do that you can use a hash table (storing key value pairs).

Just iterate over the first string and put all it's 3-substrings into the hash table as keys with values equal to 1.
Then iterate over the second string and for each 3-substring x if x is in the hash table and its value is 1, then set the value to 2.
Then iterate over the third string and for each 3-substring x, if x is in the hash table and its value is 2, then set the value to 3.
...and so on.
At the end the keys that have the value of k are the common 3-substrings.

Now just iterate once more over all the strings and remove those 3-substrings that are common.

Comment: your solution will not work if one sentence has the phrase repeated twice and one sentence does not have the phrase at all. In this case, your phrase count will come as k , but not all sentences have the phrase. ! and you will end up removing the wrong phrase.

Comment: and, just curious. why will numbers not work ? why use letters?

Comment: letter, numbers - that the same thing.
for your other comment - no it will work - note that I say you only increment if the value for r-th string is (r-1). Thus you will increment only once per 3-substring per string. So it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

First observation: replace each word with a single "letter" in a big alphabet(i.e. hash the worlds in some way), remove whitespaces and punctuation.

Now you have the problem reduced to remove the longest letter sequence that appears in *all* words of a given list. 
So you have to compute the longest common substring for a set of "words". You find it using a [generalized suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Suffix_tree) as this is the most efficient algorithm. This should do the trick and I believe has the best possible complexity.

Comment: how do you propose to convert thousands of different words into a range as small as 26? that will create clashes wont it ?

Comment: Oh no... my idea is to use bigger alphabet of course. No one said it has to have 26 letters. In fact you need to have as many letters as words. For each word you convert it to lowercase and then hash it if that hash was not met yet you give it the next natural number.

Comment: ok. y do you emphasize on letters? why will numbers not work ?

Comment: Actaully I do not say you need to use actual letters. I am simply using different terminology then you it seems. As we have a finite number of words I number them and I consider these numbers as letters in a finite alphabet. I used this explanation as suffix tree usually handles words and  thought using sequence of numbers I might confuse you. Seems I *did* confuse you but in this manner... sigh

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class remove_unique{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1 = "Everyday I do exercise if";
        String s2 = "Sometimes I do exercise if i feel stressed";
        String s3 = "Mostly I do exercise on morning";
        String[] words1=s1.split("\\s");
        String[] words2=s2.split("\\s");
        String[] words3=s3.split("\\s");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<words1.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<words2.length;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<words3.length;k++){
                    if(words1[i].equals(words2[j]) && words2[j].equals(words3[k]) 
                            &&words3[k].equals(words1[i])){
                        //Concatenating the returned Strings
                        sb.append(words1[i]+" ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(s1.replaceAll(sb.toString(), ""));
        System.out.println(s2.replaceAll(sb.toString(), ""));
        System.out.println(s3.replaceAll(sb.toString(), ""));
    }
}

//LAKSHMI ARJUNA
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be something like,

```
F = all fragments with length > 3 shared by the first 2 lines, avoid overlaps
for each line from the 3rd line and up
    remove fragments in F which do not exist in line, or cause overlaps

return sentences with fragments in F removed
```

I assume finding/matching fragments in sentences can be done with some known algo. but in terms of the time complexity for n lines this is O(n)